# How to set checked value of checkbox on filtered rows in a jQuery dataTable?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatable, filtering

I have problems settings checkboxes with checked state in a jQuery dataTable.

My setup

1. [jQuery DataTable v. 1.9.4](http://legacy.datatables.net/)
2. filtered data
3. paging enabled and filtered data spans multiple pages.

I am trying to set checked state on checkboxes in a filtered dataTable that (can) span multiple pages. I can only get my code to set the checked state on the checkboxes on the first page (maybe visible rows?) but any checkboxes on subsequent pages remain unchecked.

This is my code - fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ohj8t5kL/2/

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="myform">
  <input type="checkbox" id="selectall" /><label for="selectall">Select all</label> 
  | Search <input type="text" value="" id="dtSearch">
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</div>
```

```js
<script>
    var myList = function () {
        var dtTable;
        var init = function (){
            dtTable = $('#mytable').dataTable({
                "aaData": [
                    ["1", "name1", "1@example.org", "United States"],
                    ["2", "name2", "2@example.org", "Spain"],
                    ["3", "name3", "3@example.org", "Spain"],
                    ["4", "name4", "4@example.org", "United States"],
                    ["5", "name5", "5@example.org", "Spain"],
                    ["6", "name6", "6@example.org", "Spain"]
                ],
                "iDisplayLength": 3,
                "aoColumns": [
        { "sTitle": "", "bVisible": true, sWidth: "10%", "mRender": renderCheckBox },
        { "sTitle": "", "bVisible": true, sWidth: "25%" },
        { "sTitle": "", "bVisible": true, sWidth: "25%" },
        { "sTitle": "", "bVisible": true, sWidth: "40%" }
                ],
                "bInfo": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "sDom": "trp"
            });
            $('#dtSearch').on('keyup', dtFilter)
            $('#myform').on('click', '#selectall', selectAll);
        };

        var dtFilter = function () {
            dtTable.fnFilter($('#dtSearch').val());
        };


        var renderCheckBox = function (data, type, full) {
            return '<input type="checkbox" value="' + full[0] + '" id="c' + full[0] + '"/>';
        };

        var selectAll = function () {
            var checked = $('#selectall').prop('checked');
            // get all filtered rows
            var filteredRows = $(dtTable).dataTable()._('tr', { "filter": "applied" });
            filteredRows.forEach(function (row) {
                $('#mytable input[value="' + row[0] + '"]').prop('checked', checked);
            });
        };
        return {
            Init : init
        };
    }();

    myList.Init();
</script>
```

```html
</body>
</html>
```

Debugging `filteredRows` in the method `selectAll` shows that it contains the filtered data correctly, e.g. for the keyword Spain, `filteredRows` contains 4 rows:

```
var filteredRows = $(dtTable).dataTable()._('tr', { "filter": "applied" });
```

I suspect my problem is with the following piece of code. Any help is appreciated:

```js
 filteredRows.forEach(function (row) {
     $('#mytable input[value="' + row[0] + '"]').prop('checked', checked);
 });
```

Comment: check this extension out http://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/

Comment: (I know it's very late but) @ElliottPost That plugin isn't compatible with DataTables 1.9.4 (none of its versions).

Comment: @nonzaprej ah, sorry. I don't remember which version of Datatables I used when I used the plugin. The plugin works great otherwise, but apparently not for 1.9.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Someone developed a [fnGetFilteredNodes](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/20058/complete-solution-passing-filtered-and-or-paginated-form-fields-with-optional-check-all-feature#latest) extension method:

```js
    $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnGetFilteredNodes = function (oSettings)
    {
       var anRows = [];
       for (var i=0,iLen=oSettings.aiDisplay.length;i<iLen;i++)
       {
          var nRow = oSettings.aoData[oSettings.aiDisplay[i]].nTr;
          anRows.push(nRow);
       }
    return anRows;
    };
```

I added this and [fnGetHiddenNodes.js](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnGetHiddenNodes) and changed my selectAll method to:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dataTables.fnGetHiddenNodes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dataTables.fnGetFilteredNodes.js"></script>


    var selectAll = function() {
        var checked = $('#selectall').prop('checked');
        $('input', dtTable.fnGetFilteredNodes()).attr('checked',checked); 
    };
```

Comment: As a note for current developers - there is a newer version of JQuery DataTable, where this functionality may be supported.